# gravar struct em arquivo

Tags: c, fopen

Estou tentando gravar uma `struct` em um arquivo via linguagem c. Mas sempre que rodo o programa no `xcode` nada é gravado no arquivo.

Já tentei o sistema de permissões de arquivo, porém não há nada de errado.

código:

```
//
//  main.c
//  arquivos3
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Pessoa{
    char nome[20];
    unsigned int idade;
    float altura;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    FILE* ptr;
    char* filename = "arq_teste.dat";
    char* modo_gravacao = "w";
    struct Pessoa pessoa = {"Fernando Santos", 42, 1.75};

    //Abre o arquivo para gravação; se ocorrer erro o programa aborta.
    if ((ptr = fopen(filename, modo_gravacao)) == NULL) {
        puts("Erro ao abrir o arquivo!");
        exit(1);
    }

    fwrite(&pessoa, sizeof(struct Pessoa), 1, ptr);

    fclose(ptr);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu modo de gravação deve ser "wb" pois você não está trabalhando com um arquivo texto.

Comment: Não está neste código, mas já tentei desta forma.

Comment: Aqui funcionou corretamente e gerou um arquivo binário.

Answer (score 1):

1) Você não tem certeza em qual contexto o seu programa está sendo executado pelo `xcode` e por isso, seu arquivo de saída está sendo gravado em algum lugar "desconhecido" no seu sistema de arquivos.

Garanta que o arquivo de saída será gravado **no mesmo** diretório no qual se encontra o executável:

```
char* filename = "./arq_teste.dat";
```

2) Você está gravando o conteúdo de uma estrutura diretamente em um arquivo e precisa fazer isso em modo binário:

```
char* modo_gravacao = "wb";
```

3) Para entender melhor o problema, você precisa de um tratamento de erros mais completo, por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Pessoa {
    char nome[20];
    unsigned int idade;
    float altura;
};

int main(void)
{
    FILE* ptr;
    char* filename = "./arq_teste.dat";
    char* modo_gravacao = "wb";
    struct Pessoa pessoa = {"Fernando Santos", 42, 1.75};

    if ((ptr = fopen(filename, modo_gravacao)) == NULL) {
        puts("Erro ao abrir o arquivo!");
        return 1;
    }

    if(fwrite(&pessoa, sizeof(struct Pessoa), 1, ptr) != 1) {
        puts("Erro ao gravar conteudo no arquivo!");
        fclose(ptr);
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(ptr);

    puts("Arquivo gravado com sucesso!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O `fwrite()` deveria de ser substituído por

`fprintf(ptr, "%s %d %f", pessoa.nome, pessoa.idade, pessoa.altura);`

So usar o wordpad e já consegue ver como está a dar.

Com o fprintf pode escolher o modo de como quer gravar, o que é uma vantagem, como por exemplo

`fprintf(ptr, "%s-%d-%f", pessoa.nome, pessoa.idade, pessoa.altura);
                 ^`

Comment: Note que o autor da pergunta deseja gravar um arquivo binário e não um arquivo texto. Não tem sentido, neste caso, substituir o fwrite por fprintf.